# Addition/subtraktion/multiplikation of floats in bash with bc -l

Tags: bash, math, scripting, bc

I have some trouble with such an easy task...

Please find relevant code below:

```
loewdin_fuk=$(echo  $line_fukui|awk '{print $4}')

nbo_fuk=$(echo  $line_fukui|awk '{print $5}') 

echo "loewdin_fuk $loewdin_fuk nbo_fuk $nbo_fuk"

aver_fuk=$(($loewdin_fuk + $nbo_fuk))

\#aver_fuk=$(echo "scale=4; 0.5*($loewdin_fuk $nbo_fuk)" | bc -l)
```

The output is:

```
loewdin_fuk +0.1662 nbo_fuk +0.1865

./collectFukui.sh: line 151: +0.1662 + +0.1865: syntax error: invalid 

arithmetic operator (error token is ".1662 + +0.1865")
```

Using the command line:

```
aver_fuk=$(echo "scale=4; 0.5*($loewdin_fuk $nbo_fuk)" | bc -l)
```

leads to following output:

```
loewdin_fuk +0.1662 nbo_fuk +0.1865

(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

I don't get what's wrong... Thank you in advance!

Best,

Me

Comment: `bash` can't handle floats. Do the whole thing in `awk`.

Comment: `echo "$line" | awk '{print "Average: ", ($4 + $5)/2.0}'`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `bc` does not consider `+` to be a unary operator. So `+0.1662 +0.1865` is invalid syntax. (It would have worked ok if the first number were negative, because `-` is a unary operator.)

So if you want to use `bc`, you need to do something like:

```
aver_fuk=$(echo "scale=4; 0.5*(0$loewdin_fuk $nbo_fuk)" | bc -l)
```

Prepending 0 without a space will work whether or not `$loewdin_fuk` starts with a sign character. If you put a space in between, it would work with values with explicit sign characters, but fail on values without a sign.